# Add FULLTEXT index to Primary Key

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I need to run a search query through `FULLTEXT` index mechanism.

Now I faced with an issue, one of my `columns` which in the above search query is Primary Key, should I add a `FULLTEXT` index to it?

Any suggestion would be appreciated...

Comment: @eggyal Full-text query will ignore stopwords according to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html

Comment: @eggyal Yes, you're right - I did not describe it correctly but it's not my question, I want to know that is it possible to add `FLLTEXT` index to a `Primary Key`?

Comment: The primary key cannot be defined by a `FULLTEXT` index (for one thing, such indexes provide no uniqueness constraint); however, the primary key can be included in a `FULLTEXT` index.  It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish, or why.

Comment: The request for a full text index on a primary key columns suggests a highly suspect data model.  You are better off with primary keys being integers and data fields containing complex text.